# what is the difference between ${HOME} and $HOME in macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, environment-variables

I came across different variable mentios in my .zshrc, with curly brackets and without them. What is the difference between

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
```

and

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly brackets tell the shell exactly where the token to be replaced begins and ends.

This is often important as certain characters such as a colon or open square bracket immediately following a variable name can be meaningful to the shell, triggering possibly unwanted behaviors in how the variable substitution (technically called "parameter expansion") is handled.

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion

Please note that the colon and some other parameter expansion modifier characters date back to the original Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`), are likely part of POSIX compliance, and apply to almost all shells on almost all Unix-like OSes, not just `zsh` on macOS.

**Edited:** Removed erroneous example and focused on the colon case.

Comment: Do any of those parameter expansions actually take effect on expansions without braces? Even for zsh, this is the first time I've heard of such functionality.

Comment: This is incorrect; doing what you describe would break so much existing code as to make zsh unusable. As the page you link says @user1686: in the section for `${name}`, the only parameter modifiers recognized without braces (and only with KSH_ARRAYS off) are the prefix chars, one subscript, and colon modifiers; that does not include /string/replacement. For n isolated directory like $HOME there is no difference, but there would be for e.g. `${LIB)_x64` vs `$LIB_x64`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the correction. I've edited my Answer to remove the bad example.